# Fail to connect to the provider Reason=[connect: timeout cant be negative] Cyberark

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cyber-ark

I am getting the following error when trying to get the creds via cyber-ark SDK.

```
javapasswordsdk.exceptions.PSDKException: PDKTC006E Failed to connect to provider (Reason=[connect: timeout cant be negative], Rc=[-1])
    at javapasswordsdk.PasswordSDK.getPassword(PasswordSDK.java:4)
    at org.myorg.credentialprovider.utils.CredentialProviderUtil.getPasswordFromCP(CredentialProviderUtil.java:181)
    at org.myorg.credentialprovider.utils.CredentialProviderUtil.retrieveCredentials(CredentialProviderUtil.java:146)
    at org.myorg.module.batch.utility.CredentialUpdater.updateCredentials(CredentialUpdater.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling
```

Tried searching the cyber ark documentations but couldn't get anything relevant on the web. Also, I am not passing the timeout as **-1** by myself anywhere. Not sure why it is picking this value. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems  that the Central Credential Provider is not running. [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586358/cyber-ark-netpasswordsdk-not-able-to-connect) and
[CA docs](https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/AAM-CP/Latest/en/Content/CP%20for%20Mac/Troubleshooting-Implementation.htm)

as example (aim), you can check with:

```
ps -ef | grep appprovider
/etc/init.d/aimprv stop
/etc/init.d/aimprv start
```

or with CA logs